# payday2 demo menu script syntax error in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I get an error when I run ingame it says

[image]

also posted source on pastebin [SOURCE](http://pastebin.com/Yyk23PGW)

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

The place where the error happens:

```
menu1 = menu1 or {
{ text = "Cancel", is_cancel_button = true } 
{},
{ text = "+G0DM0DE~", callback = godmode }
{ text = "+Stamina Hack~", callback = staminahx }
{ text = "+Equipment/Tie Hack~", callback = sawsandties }
{ text = "No Recoil Or Spread!", callback = norclorsprd }
{ text = "< - Back", callback = callmenu0 },
}
```

You need to add comma between each elements of the table:

```
menu1 = menu1 or {
{ text = "Cancel", is_cancel_button = true },   --here
{},
{ text = "+G0DM0DE~", callback = godmode },     --here
{ text = "+Stamina Hack~", callback = staminahx }, --here
{ text = "+Equipment/Tie Hack~", callback = sawsandties },  --here
{ text = "No Recoil Or Spread!", callback = norclorsprd },  --here
{ text = "< - Back", callback = callmenu0 },
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the source I have a new error now. http://prntscr.com/25xtax // and new updated source is http://pastebin.com/WjRR9F7c   ** If I had to guess the errors at the end because of an extra end or missing a end right?

Comment: @user1244458 Try to solve it yourself first, and in the future when asking questions, narrow your question to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) and post the code in here, not a link to another site.

Comment: Okay the code tags was just giving me problems last night attempting to submit the code in! I will try to figure out the problem, I had a problem similar to this. The reason was too many "ends" so I had to delete a couple